# Geometrically Describing a Subspace

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

I have a practice question here and it is asking to geometrically describe this subspace in $R^3$ It is asking if it is a point, a line, or a plane or all of three-space.

Here it is:

Span {(1,-2, 1) (-2, 4, -2)}

What I attempted was to show that it was linearly independent. I got that this is a plane, but I just need to clarify how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have a plane? What happens if you multiply $(1,-2,1)$ by $2$?

In general, to solve these problems you need to prove or disprove linear independence, and if you can disprove it then you need to find a maximally linearly independent subset. The first part of the solution is always to set

$$a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + \dots + a_n v_n = 0$$

where the $v_i$ are your set of vectors and the $a_i$ are unknown. If you can solve for nonzero $a_i$ as I just did then you don't have linear independence. The details are as follows:

$$v_1 = (1,-2,1), \ \ \ v_2 = (-2,4,-2), \ \ \ a_1 = 2, \ \ \ a _2 = 1.$$

Here, $n=2$, because there are $2$ vectors in your given set. Plugging into the first equation, we get

$$a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 = 2(1,-2,1) + 1(-2,4,-2) = (2 - 2, -4 + 4, 2 - 2) = (0,0,0),$$

so since a nonzero set of $a_i$ satisfy the equation, linear independence fails.

Furthermore, since one vector is always a linearly independent set as long as it's not the zero vector, either $\{(1,-2,1)\}$ or $\{(-2, 4, -2)\}$ is sufficient to form a maximally linear independent subset. This shows that the span of that set is $1$-dimensional--that is, a line.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Nick. For a2 = 1, how does that make the vectors equal to the zero vector? Because it would be -2-2, which is -4?

Comment: Aha, it's because I made a slight error. Allow me to fix it and add a detail

Comment: The problem was, I had used the coefficient which would make your two vectors equal to each other, rather than the coefficient which would solve the equation. Of course, knowing that two vectors in a set are equal up to some scalar multiple implies that the equation is satisfied for some coefficients not all zero, but it was still a mistake on my part.

Comment: Hey, ok I see what you did now.. but I have another question in the textbook that asks for the span({0,1,1),(1,1,0)}. From what I can see, this is linearly independent because there are no values for a1 & a2 that would be a constant. How would I go from here to explain that it is a plane, line, point etc? I just want to get the hang of this, thanks for your help . Really appreciate it :)

Comment: @DavisApanasova First of all, you're correct that they're linearly independent. Now that that's out of the way, the size of a linearly independent set determines "what kind of subspace" it spans, and this is really a matter of definition more than anything else. An empty linearly independent set spans a 0-dim'l subspace (a point). A linearly independent set of just one vector spans a 1-dim'l subspace (a line). A linearly independent set of two vectors spans a 2-dim'l subspace (a plane). After that, we tend to just say that $n$ linearly independent vectors span an $n$-dim'l subspace,...

Comment: and we tend to just call that subspace an "$n$-plane" or an "$n$-hyperplane", rather than give it its own name.

Comment: This is a linearly independent set of two vectors so it spans a 2 dimensional subspace (a plane) ?

Comment: Sorry, I left that out. Yep, you've got it.

Comment: thanks for your response. I have just one last question (since my textbook doesn't have an answer key for the practice questions); I have a question that asks for the Span({(1,-1,0), (-2,1,1),(0,1,-1)}). I got this to also be linearly dependent because I found a1=2, a2=0, a3=0 and this equaled to the 0 vector. And in this question, there are 3 vectors which according to your previous definition, an n-dimensional subspace is called an n-hyperplane. But the question asks if it is a point, a line, or a plane or all of three-space. So would this be all of three-space? Hope you can response!

Comment: You're right that they're linearly dependent, but the coefficients I found were $a_1 = 2, a_2 = 1, a_3 = 1$, so be sure to double-check your calculations. Now note that if you take away $(-2,1,1)$ from that set, there's no longer any way to add nonzero scalar multiples of the remaining vectors to get the zero vector (can you see why?), so the set $\{(1,-1,0),(0,1,-1)\}$ is linearly independent. It has two elements, so this is again a plane.

Comment: Oh, if (-2,1,1) is removed from the set, then the remaining (1,-1,0),(0,1,-1) will never be equal to 0 with a constant. Is that the reason why it is a linear independent set? (1,-1,0), (0,1,-1).

Thanks Nick!